# Value in code-behind presented differently in UI

Tags: c#, .net, math, windows-phone-7

This double: `16.8999999`

after `theDouble = Math.Round(theDouble, 1)` it shows up in the debugger as 16.9 but in the UI later on it's NOT 16.9 but 16.899999.

Why is this so?

I am developing a WP7 application and however and whenever I round a certain value, it always shows up "derounded" in the UI. I have even tried to make one last round before assigning the array to the listbox's itemssource. It's really strange and I'd appreciate any help or explanation.

I have even tried to assign a value myself just before the itemssource gets set. I assign 16.89999 and round it using the above method. In the debugger I get the expected result but then in the UI I get *another* result, namely, 16.899999618. Help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does (int)(33.46639 * 1000000) return 33466389?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422027/why-does-int33-46639-1000000-return-33466389)

Comment: yeah, sorry about the title, I was just so baffled as to why it doesn't work.

Comment: Wow, I must have hit a sore spot with my title. Three downvotes! Personal record.

Comment: Do I still deserve the downvotes? It's a pretty tricky problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea but it could have something to do with how WP7 presents doubles in datacontexts. **I changed the type to float and now it works perfectly**. I hope someone in the same situation finds this question even though it's pretty downvoted.

Comment: That it works for `float` and not for `double` is purely a fluke. You'll see different results for other numbers. You should display your code with a format string if you at all can; then make the format string round properly (e.g., `%.1f`).

Comment: I guess I should ask another question on how to display values when the datacontext is bound to objects.

Answer (score 10):

Assign the value back to the variable:

```
   mydouble = Math.Round(mydouble, 1);
```

Update:

Since you updated your question, you can focus on how the value is displayed instead.

Comment: I am doing that. That's what's surprising.

Comment: you're seeing this in the debugger probably. Floating point numbers are always imprecise. Lean on how you present the value instead of worrying about it's "real" value as stored in memory.

Comment: No, I am not. Everything is fine and dandy until it gets presented in the UI.

Comment: Instead of round, use the string formatting in .net to do the rounding.

Comment: I'm assigning objects to the ItemsSource, any suggestion on how I would do what you suggested?

Answer (score 4):

Um, no: http://ideone.com/zuK9Z

I think you've made a mistake in your code. Are you doing something like this:

```
double theDouble = 16.8999999;
Math.Round(theDouble);
```

?

It should be:

```
double theDouble = 16.8999999;
theDouble = Math.Round(theDouble);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most computers use binary floating-point. Binary floating-point *cannot* represent 0.1 exactly (in binary, it's a recurring fraction). Thus, it also cannot represent 0.9 exactly either.

Comment: Almost posted the same thing...but if you read carefully you'll notice that the OP is expecting the rounding to happen in-place rather than having to assign the result to a new variable.

Comment: That's not true, though, in this case.

Comment: @minitech: Actually, it still is true: 16.9 is actually 16.89999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375 when using doubles.

Comment: @Chris: .NET is smart enough to fix this kind of thing on its own, given the actual decimal precision of the `double` type, which is 15 decimal digits. What I meant was that it doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: @minitech: .NET doesn't "fix" anything. However, I'll grant that most floating-point _display_ functions will display 16.9 because it rounds to, say, 6 decimal places, not 15. That doesn't negate my point that you _cannot_ represent 16.9 exactly using only a double.

Comment: @Chris: That definitely counts as fixing it. And no, not 6 decimal places. 15. This comes from MSDN and here's proof: http://ideone.com/qbPvB

Comment: @minitech just how would you expect .Net to know when the representation should be fixed and when it's accurate? The link you provide shows what the .NET framework does not how debuggers show the value (which was what Chris commented on)

Comment: @Rune FS: What do you mean in this phrase: " shows what the .NET framework does not how debuggers show " ?

Comment: @minitech: What Rune FS is talking about is that the .NET framework code displays a rounded value, but (some) debuggers show the real value. Sure, the number _displays_ as 16.9 when you round it (even to 15 sig figs), however, the number is not really exactly 16.9; it's just a close approximation.

Comment: @Chris: Ah, okay. Well, in response to that, I expect .NET to know when the representation should be fixed and when it's accurate, because of the "15 decimal places" rule. When displaying, it should simply round to 15 decimal places or display in scientific notation.

Answer (score 0):

Double values are not precise by nature!

That happens because Double numbers are represented with binary digits, not decimal, so that the nearest representation of the requested number is given in the result.