# C#  wrong subtraction? 12.345 - 12 = 0.345000000000001

Tags: c#, numbers, floating-point, floating-accuracy, subtraction

I am beginner in C# and I am working with floating point numbers. I need to do subtraction between these two numbers but it does not work. I know it is caused by floating point number, but how can I fix it please and if you be so good can you explain me why is it happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you want and what is your problem, please elaborate youe question..?

Comment: Post your code please. Are all the variables floats?

Comment: Can you post code? The calculation in your topic looks very strange. Normal floating point rounding doesn't cause such behavior.

Comment: Some code demonstrating the problem would help.

Comment: Post the full code, even with rounding errors and floating point stuffs you can't get that result from that inputs.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do, can you post your code snippet?

Comment: Are you sure the answer is 0.000000000000001 and not 0.345000000000001? The latter I can explain!

Comment: Title has been edited. Rob was correct.

Comment: For your new question, the simple answer is using `decimal` instead of float.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does (int)(33.46639 * 1000000) return 33466389?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422027/why-does-int33-46639-1000000-return-33466389)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Consider using decimal instead of float:

```
// Instead of this...
float a = 12.345F;
float b = 12;
float c = a - b;

// Use this: 
decimal d = 12.345M;
decimal e = 12;
decimal f = d - e;
```

Jon Skeet gives a good explanation of the differences between both types in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/618596/446681

Comment: +1: if you need any kind of numeric fidelity, `decimal` is the way to go.

Comment: Decimal is what I was looking for, thanks a lot. I wanna thank also to people who explained why it was happening.

Comment: Depends on what the numbers are for.  You should always use `decimal` for money.  But *not* for physics simulations.

Comment: Even if the exact same problem will not happen with `decimal`, it is still true that if you subtract the most significant part (such as the integral part) of a number from that number, the precision of the result is limited. For example let `decimal g = 1000000000000000000m / 7m; decimal h = 142857142857142857m; decimal i = g - h;`, one could ask: Why is my result `i` only precise up to 11 digits; I thought a `decimal` had a precision of 28 to 29 digits? So precision is still lost with `decimal`.

Answer (score 9):

This is not a c# problem, this is a computer science problem. If you want to truly understand what is going on, read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).  If you just care about why you're having the problem, it's because Float and Double are only precise to 7 and 15 digits respectively on this platform, and you need to apply rounding logic to achieve the result you are looking for.

[Float C# reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[Double C# reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx)

> Squeezing infinitely many real numbers into a finite number of bits
>   requires an approximate representation. Although there are infinitely
>   many integers, in most programs the result of integer computations can
>   be stored in 32 bits. In contrast, given any fixed number of bits,
>   most calculations with real numbers will produce quantities that
>   cannot be exactly represented using that many bits. Therefore the
>   result of a floating-point calculation must often be rounded in order
>   to fit back into its finite representation. This rounding error is the
>   characteristic feature of floating-point computation. [Goldberg 1991](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Good to find someone, who says that this is an obvious problem, and moreover this is definitely a bug (issue) in programming, which hasnt been solved. even my old calculator works well, and it's 2019 and we are still having headaches in PC.

Answer (score 6):

How exactly are you calculating?

```
        float a = 12.35F;
        float b = 12.0F;
        float ans = a - b; //0.350000381

        double x = 12.35;
        double y = 12.0;
        double ans2 = x - y; //0.34999999999999964

        decimal n = 12.35m;
        decimal m = 12.0m;
        decimal ans3 = n - m; //0.35
```

For me these calculations give the correct results.

Answer (score 1):

remember that the behavior of floating points can vary depending on the processor you are using.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683059/are-floating-point-numbers-consistent-in-c-can-they-be/6898811#6898811) is an question on this forum that deals with the subject

If you really want to dig into the subject, [here](http://www.math.utah.edu/~beebe/software/ieee/) is a good source on how to examine the behavior of floating-point

Answer (score 0):

Depending in what you you can use either decimal type, or store it as is, but round before displaying the answer